# ionic alert with right to left radio buttons

Tags: ionic-framework, radio-button

I need to design ionic-alert with radio buttons.

The default design looks like this:

[image]

But I need the radio buttons to be right to left. So I changed ths css to `direction: rtl;` and it did the job but the circle buttons dissapeared, as you can see in the following image:

[image]

How can I have ionic-alert with radion buttons aligned right to left with the circle buttons at the right of the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in `global.scss`

```
.my-custom-class {
  direction: rtl;
  .alert-radio-icon.sc-ion-alert-md {
    right: 26px;
  }
}
```

[image]

Show radio list using alertController

```
async presentAlertRadio() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      header: 'Radio',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'radio1',
          type: 'radio',
          label: 'Radio 1',
          value: 'value1',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Radio 1 selected');
          },
          checked: true,
        },
        {
          name: 'radio2',
          type: 'radio',
          label: 'Radio 2',
          value: 'value2',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Radio 2 selected');
          },
        },
        {
          name: 'radio3',
          type: 'radio',
          label: 'Radio 3',
          value: 'value3',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Radio 3 selected');
          },
        },
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Cancel');
          },
        },
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Ok');
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

if display radio button and label left to right apply below code

[image]

```
    .my-custom-class {
      direction: rtl;
      .alert-radio-icon.sc-ion-alert-md {
        right: 26px;
      }
      .my-custom-class{
          direction: ltr;
      }
    }
```